# Error when connecting to a CYC KB

Tags: database, artificial-intelligence

I am using openCyc and I am trying to connect to an image of a Cyc KB. I can browse this image on my browser (using chrome) and can successfully ping the address from the command line.

Now, when I try to create a `new CycAccess("server", "port)` the correct server and port of the image I am browsing on the browser I get an error saying connection refused which is printed out to the terminal.

For the server, it is simply xxxxx.yyyyy.com and the port is just for example `6622`. Am I formatting this wrong or something?

Why would this happen?

Thank you,
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer to my question. IDK if this well help anyone else so I am going to post it.

Answer:

The port that you typically access a CYC Image through the browser is not necessarily the port that you will access it through the OpenCyc API. When I changed the port, it solved my problem.

Rich